# Can QGIS resample Rasters during display?

Tags: raster, qgis

When I was using ArcGIS a user could resample a raster during the display (I think via layer properties under the display tab). This would smooth the appearance of the raster so it wouldn't appear pixelated when the user zoomed in too far, I found this useful when using hillshades.

I haven't found a way to do this in QGIS, but can it be done? If not is there a GDAL tool I can use to smooth the appearance of my hillshades so they don't look pixelated when they are getting near the end of their optimum scale.

Thanks
Ando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS cannot do this on-the-fly as far as I know.

For a GDAL solution try gdalwarp iterations described in [GDAL mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Resampling-With-GDAL-td2029808.html).

Comment: Thankyou. I used a slight variation of the link you referred to. I used -tr to set the resolution.

Comment: We can do raster re sampling now in master version